# Alternative for ifelse function in R to create a new numeric variable?

Tags: r, if-statement

A year ago, I created new variables (new1 & new2) with the *ifelse* statement in R:

`data$new1<-ifelse(data$v1==1||data$v2==1||data$v3==1||data$v4==1,1,0)`

`data$new2<-ifelse(data$varx==307||data$varx==301||data$varx==309||data$varx==321,1,0)`

Both statements turned out ok. To my surprise, neither of the two is working any longer since a few weeks...
Do you have any idea what might have changed and even better - do you know an alternative function that performs the same calculation?

Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: The statements seems fine to me.  Can you check the `str(data)` before doing the comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your are right, the statement works fine without NAs, so it might be due to the well-known NA-problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative apporach for the first `ifelse` would be to select the columns of interest, do a comparison (`==`) with 1, get the `rowSums` and check if it is greater than 0, then convert the logical vector to binary (`+`)

```
+(rowSums(data[c('v1', 'v2', 'v3','v4')] == 1) > 0)
```

Or with `Reduce`, loop over the subset of column, convert to a `list` of logical vectors by looping over the `list` with `lapply` and doing the comparison, then `Reduce` to a single logical vector with `|`, and coerce to binary as before

```
+(Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[c('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4')] `==`, 1)))
```

---

For the second case, it would be comparing one column with a vector of values.  So, use `%in%`

```
+(data$varx %in% c(307, 301, 309, 321))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
setToOneCondition <- data$v1==1 | data$v2==1 | data$v3==1 |data$v4==1
data$new1 <- as.numeric(setToOneCondition)
```